List of Ubuntu preinstalled drivers and their versions
Can someone please point me out to a document or link, listing the preinstalled drivers and their versions in ubuntu 22.04. I specifically want to know the version of the ice driver installed in Ubuntu 22.04. I know I can get the details using modinfo ice but want to know the specific version of the ice driver which is not mentioned.

I tried searching in the Ubuntu website, for some documentation or list. Tried modinfo as well.

What gets installed will vary on the ISO used at install, as Ubuntu 22.04 is the release, with different architectures & products available; the kernel stack being used (by default) varies on the ISO used at install time (ie. some install the GA kernel stack, some install HWE by default, with some offering OEM options too).  You can view the manifest for the ISO you install to get package versions, but it'll only show Ubuntu package versions of what's included on the ISO (which can change on applying updates, let alone package versions not always matching versions of software inside)

Don't forget the 2022-April release (22.04) has now six variations of ISOs released (ie. 22.04, 22.04.1, 22.04.2 etc..), with the GA kernel stack on 22.04 & 22.04.1 being swapped at 22.04.2 & later media with HWE (though this is largely flavor ISOs); but you only specified release; but default varies on ISO used at install don't forget for some kernel modules (aka drivers)  ps: I don't actually know what you're asking in regards ICE driver; as the there are many things in Ubuntu called ICE.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=links  has all verions numbers for all active Ubuntu releases.

@Terrance, this only shows the list of installed kernel modules in ubuntu, most of which don't have any version stated in them. Already checked this.

@guiverc, I'm using the GA kernel stack and it comes preinstalled with a intel NIC driver named ice, when I download and install a specific version from web, I see a version of the ice driver,
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-1032-realtime/updates/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ice/ice.ko
firmware:       updates/intel/ice/ddp/ice.pkg
version:        1.12.7
license:        GPL v2
something like this, but with the preinstalled one, I don't see any version, so I was trying to see how I can figure that out.
